How to select mulitple options in multiple select select menu in cakephp
This is my code for the multiple select menu in my cakephp application:
<td><?= $this->Form->select('clothCutting['.$color.'][mtr_str]', ['23'=>'23', '67'=>'67', '24'=>'24'], ['multiple' => true, 'value' => "23", 'label' => false, 'class' => 'table-processed', 'style' => 'width:100%;']) ?></td>
It will be rendered like this:

But it only selects one option. What if I want it to select multiple options.
I tried to put an array of the options I want it to select in the value attribute but it didn't work.
Like this:
<td><?= $this->Form->select('clothCutting['.$color.'][mtr_str]', ['23'=>'23', '67'=>'67', '24'=>'24'], ['multiple' => true, 'value' => "[23,67]", 'label' => false, 'class' => 'table-processed', 'style' => 'width:100%;']) ?></td>
But it is not even selecting a single option now:

What do I do?

Check the array construction inside the clothCutting['.$color.'][mtr_str] options, try this :
<td><?= $this->Form->select('clothCutting['.$color.'][mtr_str]', [23, 67, 24], ['multiple' => true, 'value' => [23, 67], 'label' => false, 'class' => 'table-processed', 'style' => 'width:100%;']) ?></td>
Here you have the related docs :
Options for Select, Checkbox and Radio Controls
